# React running a function inside onClick of a button inside parent component

Tags: reactjs, button

I have two components a child and a parent so the child is a div with a button inside it and inside the parent i call it with the onclick property with function inside it is it possible ?

Button.js

```
import React from "react";

const Button =() => {
  return(
    <div>
      <button> >Hello world</button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Button;
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Button from "./button";
import "./styles.css";

const  handleClick = () => {
  return(<h1>Hello world..!</h1>)

}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Button onClick={handleClick()} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Yes it is possible to do what you are doing, but it will give no results whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's create good button component for use the button component in multiple pages. Create own file for button component with next code:

```
import React from "react";

const Button = ({ onClick, title }) => (
  <div>
    <button onClick={onClick}>{title}</button>
  </div>
)

export default Button;
```

The button component have two props. It is `onClick` and `title`. `onClick` - it is a function. `title` - it is a string. We can use [PropTypes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) for checking types, but not right now, in this example it is not very important.

So, if you want to use the button component in multiple pages then just import your button component and pass two props to the component like next code:

```
<Button
  onClick={handleClick}
  title=">Hello world"
/>
```

It is very simple and usable. Full example with your code in the next snippet:

```js
const Button = ({ onClick, title }) => (
  <div>
    <button onClick={onClick}>{title}</button>
  </div>
)

const handleClick = () => {
  console.log('clicked');
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Button onClick={handleClick} title=">Hello world" />
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onClick` prop you have set to the `<Button />` component will never reach the `<button>` element. You have to add the `onClick` prop to the Button components props:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Button = ({ onClick }) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Hello world</button>
    </div>
  )
}

Button.defaultProps = {
  onClick: () => null,
};
Button.propTypes = {
  onClick: PropTypes.func,
};
export default Button;
```

Also note that in the parent component you should pass the function without the parenthesis in this case `<Button onClick={handleClick} />`. Keep in mind there are different ways to do this for different use cases.

Comment: So how will it be possible to reuse the same button if a specifiy the prop to be coming from App.js i want to use my button component in multiple  pages and to different functions how can i do something like that ?

Comment: I've updated the answer to use prop types and added a default prop for onClick. This way you can use this component with or without the `onClick` prop.

Docs here - https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Error is handleClick() is a function handler, so don't return a JSX template in it, 
this is a working example

```js
   // Button.js

    // import React from "react";

    const Button = props => (
        <div>
          <button onClick={props.click}>Hello world</button>
        </div>
      )
    // export default Button;

    // App.js

    // import React from "react";
    // import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    // import Button from "./button";
    // import "./styles.css";

    const  handleClick = () => {
      alert("Hello world")
      // return(<h1>Hello world..!</h1>)
    }

    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
          <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
          <Button click={() => handleClick()} />
        </div>
      );
    }

    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: thank you for replay my point is how can i use the same button for multiple components and pass different onClick functions if i  do pass or handle only one click